# How to load proprietary OMX components with GStreamer & Bellagio

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, openmax

I'm trying to stream the video of an IP Camera that exposes what I believe to be OMX components.

To grab the stream I've installed and configured GStreamer with gst-omx and Bellagio, but I can't get Bellagio to recognize and register the components.

I don't have any specific question, but would be very grateful for any pointers on how to wire this thing up.

Below are the components.
An analysis with [Cutter](https://github.com/radareorg/cutter) revealed that `libOMX_BELA.so` has much in common with Bellagio's `libomxil-bellagio.so.0`.

```
$ ls /lib | grep OMX
libOMX_ACODEC.so
libOMX_ALSA.so
libOMX_ASPL.so
libOMX_AVQE_A.so
libOMX_BELA.so
libOMX_IJPE.so
libOMX_IJPE_ENC_HW.so
libOMX_IJPE_ENC_SW.so
libOMX_IJPE_MEM_MGR.so
libOMX_VMFE.so
libOMX_VSPL.so
libOMX_VSRC.so
libOMX_VVHE.so
```

Output from `gst-inspect-1.0`

```
$ ./gst-inspect-1.0
omx:  omxmpeg2dec: OpenMAX MPEG2 Video Decoder
omx:  omxmp3dec: OpenMAX MP3 Audio Decoder
omx:  omxaacenc: OpenMAX AAC Audio Encoder
omx:  omxmpeg4videoenc: OpenMAX MPEG4 Video Encoder
omx:  omxh264dec: OpenMAX H.264 Video Decoder
omx:  omxmpeg4videodec: OpenMAX MPEG4 Video Decoder
staticelements:  bin: Generic bin
staticelements:  pipeline: Pipeline object

Total count: 2 plugins, 8 features
```

Trying to register the components with `omxregister-bellagio`, nothing gets registered:

```
# ./omxregister-bellagio -v /lib
 Scanning directory /lib/
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_ACODEC.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_ALSA.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_ASPL.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_AVQE_A.so
OMX-could not load /lib/libOMX_BELA.so: /lib/libOMX_BELA.so: undefined symbol: sqrt
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_IJPE.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_IJPE_ENC_HW.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_IJPE_ENC_SW.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_IJPE_MEM_MGR.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_VMFE.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_VSPL.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_VSRC.so
 Scanning library /lib/libOMX_VVHE.so
 0 OpenMAX IL ST static components in 0 libraries succesfully scanned
```

Comment: I would first try to solve an error: `OMX-could not load /lib/libOMX_BELA.so: /lib/libOMX_BELA.so: undefined symbol: sqrt`  `sqrt` is missing which is weird to say the least.  Did you compile it by yourself?

Comment: I've never used bellagio; why do you need it? Gstreamer provides every tool you need for streaming

Comment: According to this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/chromebook-arm/+bug/1085370 , there is a certain OpenMAX implementation that will not work with Bellagio.

Comment: @user8408080 could you please provide more details? How would I go about playing from these OMX components using gstreamer only? Thank you

Comment: I don't know exactly how your your camera supplies the video signal. Is it maybe rtsp?

Comment: @user8408080 unfortunately no rtsp is provided, that's actually the motive for me to be doing this.

Comment: Well the camera has to send its signals in some way, thst would be the first thing to find out. If it was just in `/dev/video0` or a rtsp server, that would be the easiest solution, but we should also be able to handle other ways of transporting the video signal

Comment: @user8408080 the stream is only available on a proprietary mobile app (no `/dev/video` devices), I believe this to be on purpose to keep the customer on their ecosystem. That's why I'm trying to find an alternative ways of streaming the camera.

Comment: I think in this case, it's very hard to find a general solution. Maybe you can somehow find out, how the app gets its signal and then we can proceed to grab that

Comment: @user8408080 the app itself grabs an encrypted H.265 stream through the network. The encrypted part is what throws me off from that solution :\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189890/discussion-between-user8408080-and-telmo-marques).